# IIF statement is showing a 0 where I know there is a value

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a dataset with values that I'm am trying to put into an SSRS report. Here is some example data:

| Fund# | last week amount | YTD Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $100 | $1500 |
| 2 | $0 | $300 |
| 3 | $500 | $500 |
| 4 | $0 | $0 |

The first column in my SSRS report is a fixed list of fund names in the certain order that I want them to appear and I want to insert the amounts from the dataset into the row with the corresponding fund name and into the right column.

I tried to get the amount for Fund 1 from last week ($100) to appear in the  report using the following expression:
`=iif(Fields!fund_no.Value=1,fields!last_wk_amt.Value,0)`

However, this is returning a 0 value but I know it should read 100. This seems pretty simple, but I just can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your field is an aggregate of the dataset. The IIF statement works on a ROW basis. In your expression, it finds the first row (which is apparently not 1) and returns the evaluation.

I believe it would work correctly if you SUM the IIF:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!fund_no.Value = 1, Fields!last_wk_amt.Value, 0))
```

If your AMT field is not a decimal value, you'd need to convert the zero to a decimal to avoid an error about aggregating mixed data types:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!fund_no.Value = 1, Fields!last_wk_amt.Value, CDEC(0)))
```

Comment: my field is not an aggregate. but this did the trick actually. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidRosen Welcome to SO! You should mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left under the vote up/down arrows). This helps others find answers to similar questions, otherwise your question will look like it has no accepted answer.